# animating a sliding footer bar onhover with js/jquery

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to add something like a sliding or animating footer area that will appear on hover. Right now I have something like:

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
alert("testing");
$('#bar').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id= "bar" class="visable">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
height:3em;
background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition:all 1s;
}
.visable{
height: 1em;
background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition:all 1s;
}
```

however this is not working as intended. The intent is to basically recreate something like: http://www.flvs.net/Pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I haven't checked out the code, toggleClass may be what that example you linked to uses.  toggleClass doesn't allow animate, but a workaround is to use css for the transition:

```
transition:all 1s;
```

and then js:

```
$('#bar').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('moo');
});
```

Since there's no separate button, there's no chance of it jumping back and forth if the cursor isn't hovering over the trigger.

All together: http://jsfiddle.net/cuz99vtj/1/

You would have to style things to get the look you want, but that should give you the idea.

Comment: hi im trying your solution but im getting an error saying: 'webkitIDBCursor' is deprecated. Please use 'IDBCursor' instead. Or, it is not working for some other reason.

Comment: I'm not sure where "webkitIDBCursor" is. Maybe try removing "-webkit-transition: all 1s;
" from the css?  You're testing the fiddle, right?

Comment: well i did get it to work but it doesn't really work the way  i need. It kind of just pushes the bottom of the page down and you cant really see the animation.

Comment: Assuming you've already styled the divs to get the orientation and appearance you want, it sounds like you will want to keep fiddling with the css to get everything to move the way you want.  Try putting position:relative; on the moo div, for starters, and go from there.  The hard part is done, it's just experimenting with css from here on.

Comment: Check this out and see what I mean:  http://jsfiddle.net/cuz99vtj/2/  Just added a couple of style modifications.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hb7ttqL8/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('#footer').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
            bottom: '0px'
        },500)
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
            bottom: '-50px'
        },500)
    }
);
```

**css:**

```
#wrap{width:95%;height:2000px;background:wheat;}
#footer{position:absolute;width:95%;height:60px;bottom:-50px;background:yellow;}
```

---

The wrap is unnecessary -- it just represents your web page.

The footer stuff is the necessary bit. Note that the footer element is styled as being `position:absolute`, which removes it from the flow and allows you to position it anywhere on the screen.

**In fact, `fixed` is a better choice - try changing that.**

`absolute` positions the div in relation to the document, or to the first parent element with `position:xxxxxxx` styling (relative, absolute or fixed). `Fixed` positions the element relative to the browser window.

We use `stop()` with `animate()` to prevent run-on animations, where the element continues bouncing once for each hover action.